# How to select the same categorical observation in 2 different columns in R

Tags: r, subset, categorical-data

I had a huge merged dataframe from 2 sources. I am interested in finding the misscoding of 2 categorical variables but because these 2 are from different sources they are not coded the same.

For example:

```
df

col1 levels: DM,GDM,NO,UNTIME,NOTKNOWN

col2 levels: type 1 dm, type 2 dm, gdm, hx of gdm,resolve,..
```

clearly they are different. So, I tried to recode col2 in similar way to col1 and I've done this successfully using `mapvalue` from `plyr` package

when I tried to subset the data by `col1==col2`
I always get the error level set of values are different 
note I tried the argument `as.is=TRUE` in `read.csv` but nothing works.

Comment: Maybe just `levels(df$col1) <- tolower(levels(df$col1))`

Comment: I had no problem with this the final categories for both columns is DM,GDM,NO,UNTIME,NOTKNOWN

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     filter(as.character(col1) == toupper(as.character(col2)))
```